# Updating Table View after Updating Values in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm able to successfully update my entries in Firebase, for it shows up on the console, but not the table view. If I restart my app the changes will then show, but I want them to show immediately.

My approach is to edit the array that populates the tableview as soon possible under the "ChildChanged" notification.

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("One of the entries were changed so we're reloading the table view")

        if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
        {
            let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"

            names[I_Need_This_Index] = fullname
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

As you can see, I just need to locate index of what I need, for I already have the "fullname" value which is the edited value that I wish to update the table view with.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup the index using the key of the changed child. Therefore a dictionary could be set up initially to map the keys for all children to the index of your tableview cell when receiving all values.

Edit:
If you need the old value itself you have to obtain the initial change snapshot yourself.

Comment: That sounds like something I should probably do. However the value of my snapshot is the newly updated value, whereas I'm trying to get the old value

Comment: The old value is not included in the change snapshot. Take a look at the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.
You have to obtain the old value yourself if needed. Another idea would be to just use the initial snapshot as your table view model to have all the information (key, old value etc.) in place.

Comment: hmm..how would i go about doing that?